# General algorithm to find a minimal branching program

Tags: finite-automata

Given a general branching program, is there an algorithm which can find an equivalent branching program $P$ of minimal length. That is $|P| \leq |P'|$ for all equivalent branching program $P'$.

If not, are their some specific cases where this algorithm exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean branching programs in the sense of generalized binary decision diagrams (see [here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~madhusudan/courses/Spring2018/scribe/lect03.pdf)).

Now the question is whether by "length", you mean "size" or "depth". I will answer the "size" version here, as you will most likely mean that (and the depth version has some intricacies).

We can represent a smaller solution in space not larger than the input size. Furthermore, checking two branching programs to be equivalent is a problem contained in the complexity class co-NP.

Hence, we can define an algorithm in $\Sigma^P_2$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy)) for finding if there exists a smaller equivalent branching program by letting it first *guess* a smaller solution, and then *verify* it to be correct using the co-NP equivalence checking oracle.

Note that this may not be an algorithm that is complexity-theoretically optimal. However, the existence of this algorithm answers your question with a "yes".